# SimpleMappingExceptionResolver catching NotAuthorizedException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a base exception handler defined like this:

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="errors.exception-handling" />
</bean>
```

and I have my controller methods with security like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequestMapping(value = "/Home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession sess) {
}
```

Now I have my NotAuthorized handler configured to redirect you to the login page if you hit /Home.   However, with the exceptionResolver,  I just get my page saying that there was an error.  If I comment out the exceptionResolver it works fine.

How do I get it to ignore NotAuthroized and other such security exceptions?

Comment: can you post your handler code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it like this

```
<property name="exceptionMappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="org.springframework.security.AccessDeniedException">loginPageUrl</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

UPDATE:

You can specify `excludedExceptions` as well to ignore NotAuthroized exception and let it be processed separately.

Comment: That won't work.  I have a strict filter setup, and simply redirecting to the login page won't work.  Is there a way to set an exceptionMappings to a bean?  ie ref="myAccessDeniedHandler"

Comment: What about ExcludedExceptions? You can add them to your exceptionResolver to skip their resolving

Comment: Change your answer to ExcludedExceptions and I will mark it correct.  Thanks!